# MP3 changes to binary file when copied to external drive

Tags: mp3, binary

Small issue but curious.  I have one mp3 file that changes type to binary when I copy it.  If I force it to open with an mp3 player it will play but if I double click it to play it won't play - it opens in an editor.

It's just one file and the only one that does it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default application that is used to open files of a given type. This will allow you to open your preferred application when you double-click to open a file. For example, you might want your favorite music player to open when you double-click an MP3 file.

Select a file of the type whose default application you want to change. For example, to change which application is used to open MP3 files(which was opening in the editor), select a `.mp3` file.

- `Right-click` the file and select **Properties**.
- Select the `Open With` tab.
- Select the application you want and click Set as default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that's not what I was inquiring about; I understand about file association. The problem I have is a unique file that changes type - i.e., it changes from xyz.mp3 to xyx.bin - when copied to another location.  Very unusual and the only file out of dozens that does it.